# SQL joins confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

what is problem in this join???
The console says

```
Error Code: 1051
Unknown table 'invlabtes'


SELECT invlabtes.*, invgatepass.BuiltySupp FROM invlabtes FULL JOIN invgatepass ON(invlabtes.GatePassNO=invgatepass.InwardNo AND invlabtes.GatePassDate=invgatepass.EntryDate AND invlabtes.VehicleNo=invgatepass.VehicleNo) WHERE  invlabtes.Code='*****'
```

If I replace the Full join with inner join then the query returns an entry.

All I want is to fetch data from invlabtes table based on invlabtes.Code even if the join condition fails and invgatepass has no matching builtySupp

Comment: Uhhh.. does the table `invlabtes` exists in your db? Maybe misspelled or you maybe selected/configured the wrong db? Local or remote, maybe you forgot to add the table in the remote db..

Answer (score 1):

Mysql doesn't support `FULL` keyword and turns it into table alias. So your invlabtes table is now named FULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return data always from invlabtes table even if it doesn't has match in invgatepass, try using LEFT JOIN instead, as Mysql doesn't supports full joins

```
SELECT 
invlabtes.*, invgatepass.BuiltySupp 
FROM 
invlabtes LEFT JOIN 
invgatepass 
ON
invlabtes.GatePassNO=invgatepass.InwardNo
AND 
invlabtes.GatePassDate=invgatepass.EntryDate 
AND 
invlabtes.VehicleNo=invgatepass.VehicleNo 
WHERE  
invlabtes.Code='*****'
```